# Navigation between screens (Activities) (Android 2.2)

Tags: android

I have application with several screens. For each screen I have created separate Activity. Question: how to navigate from one screen to another screen so that new activity is not created if such activity exists on "back stack"? My idea was to use launch mode "singleTask" however according to Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) this is not recommended! Does anyone had similar issues? Thanks!

Comment: moving activities around in the back stack is not recommended. i would suggest you try to close activities until you get back to the one you want

Comment: What makes you want to do this? It's not recommended because you can cause all sorts of other problems by doing this.

Comment: @Joru  - What makes me to do this? - How else then I should create navigation between screens? I have screens which alows user to enter the data and in last screen data is processed + from last screen user can navigate to every other screen to correct entered data.

Comment: In this case using startActivityForResult and implementing the on result method would be sufficient.

Comment: @Joru - startActivityForResult() will not allow to switch between screens (in my case - switch between activities)

Answer (score 1):

Add [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) in the `Intent` you use with `startActivity()`.